# What is the correct mathematical language in French to distinguish between vertex and angle?

Tags: mathématiques

I was presented on Facebook by a French puzzle from one of my French relatives as follows:

Combien d'angles possède un cube?

With 2, 4, 6 or 8, as the possible choices. Now I know there are 24 angles in a cube, but 8 vertices. Google translator is telling me that l'angle translates to corner as well as angle. Now, in English, vertices can be called corners, but the latter is less formal. So what are the terms used by French mathematicians to refer to vertices and angles?

Addendum: Having now read several comments, I need to be clear that in English, vertex is the main word used for the intersection of lines/sides in a polygon (2D figure) or lines/edges in a polyhedron. And, to complicate matters, with a polyhedron in 3D, 3 planes can intersect to form a vertex, not just three lines. But, and this is important, in any dimension, linear objects are points, lines, planes and thereafter, for linear objects of dimension greater than 2, hyperplanes. In all dimensions, including and beyond 2, angles are the orientation between lines, planes and hyperplanes in various combinations of all three.

My specific question is, what are the correct French mathematical term for the specific English mathematical terms, vertex and angle? It's not about everyday uses or confusions of those terms, which are legion.

Comment: Neither of these choices are **right**. A cube only has one angle: the *angle droit*! ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Mais tu vois, on ne dit pas trop qu'un cube a un _angle_. C'est pas clair en 3D. On dirait plutôt qu'il y a un angle entre deux plans qui contiennent 2 faces du cube, par exemple, ou directement entre deux faces du cube.

Comment: @Frank Ne prends pas trop au sérieux mon commentaire, mais tous les angles qu'on peut mesurer sur un cube sont quand même droits...

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, oui, je sais, j'ai bien compris. Je faisais juste remarquer qu'un "angle" c'est une notion de géométrie du plan, alors qu'un cube est un objet dans un espace à 3 dimensions, donc la notion d'"angle" pour un cube n'est pas immédiatement précise, si on veut être technique :-)

Comment: Please take it from an English mathematician using English maths language that there are 12 edges, 8 vertices, 6 faces and 24 angles in a cube. It could, perhaps, be argued that there are more than 24 angles in a cube because there are 24 between unique pairs of intersecting lines, but also 12 between the 12 unique pairs of intersecting faces, but it starts to get counter productive. A cube can be defined as simply as the twelve edges produced by the intersection of three, equidistant, mutually perpendicular, parallel pairs of planes in 3D linear space.

Comment: I won't answer the question since I have no mathematical knowledge, but I'd like to point out from a very layman's perspective that the French word *angle* can indeed be synonym of *coin* (corner) in, for example, *le coin de la pièce* (the corner of the room), and if anyone asked me *Combien d'angles possède un cube?* I'd answer 24 straight away. On the other hand I'd say un cube a *8 sommets* and *un cube a 6 faces*.

Comment: Similar example with mathematical terms, a 'manifold' is a 'variété' in French and a 'variety' is a 'variété algebrique' in French because variété is already taken.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your revised question is contained in the comments, but since you still seem unsatisfied, I will summarize them in an answer.

The word for a *vertex* in French is *un sommet*. This is the correct translation both in graph theory (where a graph has vertices and edges), for two-dimensional polygons, and for three-dimensional polyhedra.

In mathematical English, the word *angle* is not generally used for edges of a cube. Polygons have vertices and sides (or edges). Polyhedra have vertices, edges and faces (or facets).

In French, an *edge* of a polygon is called *un coté.* An *edge* of a polyhedron is called *une arête*. An edge of a graph is also called *une arête*.

The use of the word *angle* as the intersection of two rays, or as a measure of such an intersection (in radians or degrees) is translated to French as *un angle*. For example:

> The sum of the angles of a triangle is 180 degrees.
> La somme des angles d'un triangle est égale à 180°.

The intersection of two planes in three dimensions also forms an *angle*; for example, two perpendicular planes intersect at an angle of 90°. This usage of *angle* is also translated as *angle* in French.

Comment: The definitions and translations in  [Termium Plus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=enw&srchtxt=VERTEX), (filtering → mathematics →plane geometry) are reliable, they seem to concur with what you say.

Comment: Unsatisfied is the wrong word. I would like to be able to carry out the usual Stack Exchange protocol. My addendum was merely to add context for people who aren't mathematicians. I didn't change my original question at all. I will ultimately accept the answer that I think has best answered my original question.

Comment: I don't think angles (24 in a cube) are mathematically  a very important feature of polyhedra, and I wouldn't be surprised if French mathematicians don't have a word for them.

Answer (score 6):

This sentence does not sound like mathematical language, but I guess facebook quizz are not made by Math teachers.

One would expect something like :

> Combien de sommets possède un cube ?

see here : [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommet_(géomètrie)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommet_(g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie))

Comment: You might add that *angle* is indeed the correct translation for *angle* for mathematics – at least for some meanings of *angle* – although according to [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube), a cube has *douze arêtes* and not *douze angles*.

Comment: @PeterShor An _angle_ would be about 2 lines in a plane. We can say _l'angle entre deux plans_, but the intersection of 2 planes would be an _arête_ in a geometrical object like a cube. Otherwise, the intersection of 2 planes in general is just _la droite formée par l'intersection de deux plans_.

Comment: Also, _arête_ does not seem to work for planar figures. We don't say _une arête d'un triangle_, but _un côté d'un triangle_. _Arête_ seems to be specific to 3D.

Comment: @Frank: That makes sense — an *arête* is a ridge, and a *sommet* is a peak. So if anything's surprising, it's that *sommet* is used for vertices in two dimensions.

Comment: In English in 2D polygons you have sides, vertices and angles and in 3D polyhedrons you have edges, faces, vertices and angles.

Comment: Please see my OP edit.

Comment: @GeoffPointer There is something like corner/angle in the French _angle_, yes.

Comment: I'm not sure why 4 people have upvoted this answer because it has not yet fully answered my initial question: "What is the correct mathematical language in French to distinguish between vertex and angle?". The puzzle is not the question, it is an explanation as to how I came to need an answer to the question in the first place. If I am to be able to up tick an answer, it needs to be complete.

Comment: @GeoffPointer As said in another comment I have no mathematical knowledge, but I have lots of dictionaries, monolingual and bilingual, I've just checked and they all concur: the French for **vertex** is ***sommet***. (The word vertex can be used in French but not in geometry).  And it seems that the English **"angle"** translates by ***angle***. I've checked this [article](https://www.techno-science.net/glossaire-definition/Cube.html) about cube and it' the words they use,  ([wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube) gives the same words as well.

Comment: Je n'ai pas plussoyé ta réponse à ce point parce que je n'en savais rien, mais la question m'a interpelée vu que 24 ne figurait pas dans les réponses possibles et j'ai fait des recherches de novice en mathématique. Si tu ajoutes que angle en anglais c'est angle en français je vais plussoyer, vu qu'il me semble que c'est ça que demande la question.

Comment: @GeoffPointer "an explanation as to how I came to need an answer to the question in the first place" : I'd say because asking *Combien d'angles possède un cube?* with just "2, 4, 6 or 8" as possible answers doesn't make sense, which is what this answer is implicitly saying, the word *angles* is not used properly in the question and it should have been *sommets*.

Comment: @GeoffPointer As you may know, languages are not bijections of each others. Because you may say "a cube has 24 angles" in English does not mean the sentence "un cube possède 24 angles" does exist in french. As an engineer I've personnally never read it.

Comment: @XouDo C'est "techniquement" correct, mais je partage ton étonnement en entendant cette phrase. Je pense que ce facteur de surprise provient du fait qu'on associe "angle" à une notion dans le plan, alors qu'un cube est un objet 3d. On peut certes trouver des angles en 3d, mais il faut préciser alors que dans un plan, c'est plus facile.

Comment: XouDo @Frank Ici l'inculte en géométrie qui cherche à s'instruire (so be kind to me !). Un cube a 6 faces,  chaque face est un carré qui a 4 angles droits, je vois donc 24 angles sur le cube si je le fais tourner (pour voir toutes les arêtes je dois aussi le faire tourner), alors pourquoi ne peut-on pas dire qu'un cube a 24 angles ? (Je pourrais aussi dire que le cube a 8 sommets et chaque sommet est le sommet de 3 angles). Pourquoi  dites-vous qu'on ne peut pas dire ça ? Est-ce une raison scientifique, culturelle, ou autre (ce que vous dites dans vos commentaires ne me satisfait  pas !)

Comment: Whey do you say the sentence doesn't exist because you have never read it? I know there are lots of things I have never read or heard of that exist... "There are more things in Heaven and Earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy"...

Comment: @None je n'ai pas dit "je ne l'ai jamais lue, donc cette phrase n'existe pas". J'ai dit : le fait que cette phrase soit (éventuellement) utilisée en anglais n'implique pas qu'elle se dise en Français, et, accessoirement je ne l'ai jamais entendue ni lue dans ma scolarité et mes études. Ce n'est pas tout à fait pareil. On comprend bien l'idée des "24 angles", mais les angles sont une notion dans le plan (2D donc) qu'on utilise pour des figure 2D : triangles polygones etc. Alors qu'une cube est dans l'espace (3D).

Comment: It seems I misunderstood "Because you may say "a cube has 24 angles" in English does not mean the sentence "un cube possède 24 angles" does exist in french." So far I'm inclined to think the whole thing is a question of teaching traditions, I will look into it unless someone here knows.

Comment: @None _Pourquoi dites-vous qu'on ne peut pas dire ça?_ Je n'ai pas dit qu'on ne pouvait pas le dire :-) On dit que c'est juste un peu surprenant a priori. C'est une raison d'usage, je pense.

Answer (score 3):

*What is the correct mathematical language in French to distinguish between vertex and angle?*

A vertex (*sommet* or just *point*) and an angle (*angle*) are never confused in French.

My guess is then that the quiz was talking about solid angles (*angles solides*) with which the answer '8' is valid.

A cube has indeed 8 vertices but from each of them also 8 solid angles encompassing one eighth of the space: 4/8 = /2 steradians.

Comment: Oui, l'_angle solide_ vient à l'esprit, puisqu'un cube est un objet dans un espace à 3 dimensions. Mais je ne sais pas si c'est cela qu'on recherche ici.

Comment: @Frank Disons que c'est une réponse compatible avec l'intitulé de la question du quiz et les choix qu'il propose alors que deux, quatre et six sont plus difficiles à envisager.

Comment: Il n'y a que moi pour te plussoyer? Les _angles solides_ ne sont pas très populaires... :-) En plus, les angles solides ont le mérite de mesurer pi/2, qui est la même valeur qu'un angle droit dans le plan - très satisfaisant.

Comment: @Frank Le stéradian n'attire pas foule ;-) C'est pourtant une manière de résoudre le postulat incorrect de l'OP.

Comment: Effectivement, ça pourrait être ça. Mais est-ce habituel d'utiliser "angle" tout court pour parler d'angle solide ?

Comment: @XouDo Il n'est déjà pas courant de parler d'angles solides en général donc difficile de dire que c'est courant. Dans un quiz, ça me paraît possible pour ne pas donner trop d'indices.

Comment: @XouDo Non, pour les angles solides, on précise "solide" en général. Mais c'est une notion un peu plus pointue qui n'apparaît peut-être pas trop dans les présentations grand public.